How to Reference Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web class from a non-web project?
I have a class library (vintage .NET Core 2.x) that I'm upgrading to .NET 8. There's a method that returns SelectListItem from the namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering. Like this:
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetOrganization()
{
   ...
   return new List<SelectListItem>();
}

This namespace use to be part of a package that I could just reference, but now it's part of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web. To get access to this name space, I can set my Class Library Project file to start with this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

But then .NET thinks I need a main() class because it thinks I'm building a web application.
How to Reference Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web class from a non-web project?
Thanks!!

If you need to use types from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering namespace without turning your project into a web application, just use Microsoft.AspNetCore.App meta package in your class library csproj file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>


This was perfect. Thank you.
